# How to retrieve a sitecore hyperlink?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sitecore

**Situation:**
Imagine that I have an item(page) located at 'sitecore/Content/Home/mypage' in my content tree. I want to create a hyperlink to this item in my .aspx layout.

**Question:**
How can I create a hyperlink to this item in my .aspx layout?

(*Can't remember the proper syntax for `<asp:Hyperlink>`*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if in Adil's example, the URL is processed by the LinkProvider?
I would usually bind the NavigateUrl property in my code-behind

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlHyperLink" runat="server" Text="my link text" />
```

then in C#

```
hlHyperLink.NavigateUrl = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("path_to_item"));
```

Comment: Do I need to touch the codebehind for simple things like hyperlinks?? That would be unfortunate.. Is that not annoying? Or does everyone accept it as the best way to do it for whatever reason?

Comment: @EricTurner, it depends on context. In some cases it makes sense to link to a path, in others you want to link to an item based on an ID.

Comment: @EricTurner How would you otherwise propose to create a link in the Layout's code file, if you don't want to edit it? If you want a link on a page and it has a Rich Text field you could use that. But that would be only for that page. Maybe we have misunderstood what you want to accomplish? Do you want to add a link that is on all pages that use that Layout? Or is there just a page with some text, where you want to have a link?

Comment: Also, if you have a General Link or Internal Link field on your context item, you can use <sc:Link> to render a link without touching code behind.  But don't over-engineer this.  If it's a static link, then the simplest thing to do is just put the <a> tag in your markup.

Comment: With your codesnippet you may get a null reference exception. You want to first try to fetch the item before you use the GetItemUrl method.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to get an Item's url in code, whether or not you're using it in a link, you can use `Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, options)`.

I recommend against using it with a single parameter (`GetItemUrl(item)`), as it wont respect configuration options (such as disabling the language string as part of the path: `/en/path/to/item` might appear instead of `/path/to/item`).

To use the config options, you can clone the default URL options:

```
var opts = (UrlOptions) UrlOptions.DefaultOptions.Clone();
var url = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, opts);
```

I use this often enough that I use the following extension method:

```
public static string GetUrl(this Item source, bool absolutePath = false)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    var options = (UrlOptions) UrlOptions.DefaultOptions.Clone();
    options.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = absolutePath;
    return LinkManager.GetItemUrl(source, options);
}
```

The advantage to using this format is that it allows you to identify an item by ID and link to it no matter where it lies in the content tree.